# How to wash a 10-month-old whilst camping for 4 days?

Tags: infant, bathing, outdoor

We are taking our 10-month-old baby camping this summer. It will be four days of festival. We were planning to just sit him in a bucket for washing.

Does anyone have any suggestions/experience for baby washing whilst camping?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting! How long is the camping trip, and what facilities are available (i.e., is it extremely primitive, or will there be some communal bathrooms in the area)?

Comment: Four days of festival :-)

Comment: For 4 days I would use a washcloth for hands and face, and not otherwise wash your baby. My kids survived having one bath a week as babies :).

Comment: +1 For four days - no washing at all. He is going to get dirty about 20 seconds after he exits that bucket anyway. Not sure what kind of camping this is, but swimming in a lake is usually refreshing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two options we used when camping with babies that age were:

- Baby wipes - useful in all cases, but especially so for short camping trips, as you don't need to deal with water, heating, disposal etc., and can simply carry out the wipes along with nappies and other waste.
- Cloth wash - as long as you can heat water, you can then dip a cloth or sponge in it to wash baby, starting with the face, and working downwards.

For both, if you are in cold air or a cold tent, you will want to dry each washed part soon after washing, so baby doesn't get too cold. If you have good weather this can be a wonderful time with your baby, but plan for the worst.

**Edit:** For a 4 day I'd be tempted to just go with the baby wipes. For baby and for adults :-)

Answer (score 5):

An extra-large saucepan is excellent for washing a baby while camping.

You can heat the water (not too hot!) on a gas burner and then take the pan off the heat, check the water temperature, and add the baby.

I resisted the temptation to add carrots and onions and take a picture. :)

Comment: The critical part is: FIRST take pan off the heat, THEN add baby :-). The other way around will not cause happiness.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a shower available, take your child with you.

The best way is to go showering with two persons: person A goes in the shower and makes sure the temperature is right. Person B hands the child over to person A. Wash the child and rinse (watch out: if your soap is too slippery, you might wash the top first, then rinse, and then wash the bottom, or in whatever order you like). Don't forget to play with the water together!
When you're done, you hand over the child to person B again who can dry and dress the child.

If you're alone, it is also possible, but it will take some more preparation. Make sure you have dry towels and clothing for the both of you already unpacked.